# Prolog debug mode - Last Call Optimisation

Tags: debugging, prolog

So the Prolog interpreter implements Last Call Optimisation - so something like...

```
length([], Acc, Acc).
length([_|T], Acc, X) :- NewAcc is Acc+1, length(T, NewAcc, X).
```

can be called in O(1) space.

However, if I enter debug mode - this is disabled.

My question is just "why?". Surely this breaks the whole point of debugging? We can no longer see what the program is doing properly...?

Comment: You can see *what* it does, you just can't see *how* it does it. Tail call optimization is just that - an optimization; logically, your program remains the same.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Logically it does - but errors such as stack overflows can occur very easily without that optimisation in place. Bugs are not going to be from a purely logical origin. It seems odd to disable LCO in debugging mode, when it's possible for LCO to be the cause of some bug? At best it seems, if not actually damaging, then merely pointless to go about disabling it?

Comment: `length/2` is often a predefined predicate. Actually, it is defined in the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#length). So maybe you are not even debugging what you think it is? In any case, using a debugger for Prolog is not very helpful for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Its rather choice point elimination than last call optimization.
If the debugger wants to serve all the ports of Byrds
box model, i.e.:

```
          +--------+
   Call ->|        |-> Exit
          |        |
   Fail <-|        |<- Redo
          +--------+
```

He needs additional choice points. So I guess it is not
only last call optimization but also choice point optimization
which goes down the drain during debugging.

In the length/2 example a choice point can be eliminated
through indexing when you call length/2 with the first
argument instantiated.

There are some debuggers, for example SWI-Prologs debugger,
which follow the choice point elimination of the normal
interpreter to some extend. So in SWI-Prolog you don't see 
all ports always.

Bye